# Free portable Message Sequence Chart Generator

Tags: windows, gratis, portable, message-sequence-chart

My Message Seqence Chart Generator of choice is [Msc-generator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/msc-generator/). Alas, I cannot find a portable version.

What altrernatives are there? Must

- run on Windows
- be gratis
- for commerical use

Preferably, like my favourite, accept ascii text as input (e.g define two columns, sender & recevier, then send a message by `sender->recevier:message name;`) and show me my MSC in a GUI as I draw it, event by event.

However, I will accept a pure GUI solution, with no ascii inpput (which means that I cannot feed it the output of other programs).

I am aware of [msc-gen](http://www.mcternan.me.uk/mscgen/), but that, though portable, is only command line driven; I would prefer to have the option of choice between command line & GUI. Any others?

Comment: http://www.evalaze.de/en/home/ use this to make it portable. or something like molebox : http://alternativeto.net/software/molebox-virtualization-solution/ . You can use resource hacker to find the dlls that it uses on runtime and package them into a single executable.

Comment: also http://www.cameyo.com/

Comment: sorry dependency walker is the tool, not resource hacker : http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can pack all dependencies in one executable. Such programs like [BoxedApp Packer](https://www.boxedapp.com/boxedapppacker/) and [Enigma Virtual Box](https://enigmaprotector.com/en/aboutvb.html) can create a portable version of the program. Works for Windows.

BoxedApp is not gratis, but I like this programm. [OP note: single user $299, site license $3,999]

[Molebox](http://www.molebox.com) also was good [OP note: looks like [Docker](https://www.docker.com/). See also [5 Container Alternatives to Docker](https://containerjournal.com/2019/01/22/5-container-alternatives-to-docker/)]

Comment: Thanks. That is good to know. Alas, though, I want to download it at work, and can't use USB there.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. This fact somewhat complicates the situation. Perhaps you could use some kind of data warehouse to download it at work? You probably already thought about it. Hope you'll find a good solution. May be you have solved the problem?

Comment: I updated your answer; added some links and notes. Hope you don't mind

Comment: On reflection, I want a portable app - not the means to make one.

Answer (score 2):

Summing up my comments above :

Use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find all the dll's that are necessary for your software.
Use a tool like [molebox](http://alternativeto.net/software/molebox-virtualization-solution/) to package everything in one portable executable.
Final step: enjoy your Message Seqence Chart Generator everywhere.

Comment: I will try this & get back to you. It sounds like a good, generic approach for any application.

Comment: Alas, it proved much too complicated, with dependencies upon dependencies :-(

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Mawg good for others who will try this also.